# Jquery function does not work after change element's attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements (images in `<a>` tags) list which arranged by dynamic ID. It is possible to select only one of those. Assume that I select any element. This time, I change its style and set "SelectedItem" value to its name attribute to find the selected item in future.
I want that, when mouse over selected item, to change its src value, but jquery function does not work, because I set name="SelectedItem" attribute with javascript, in runtime, it works after reload a page. When I set name="SelectedItem" in the code (default, before runtime) it work. But I want to do it without reloading a page.

[image]

Shortly, when I do select operation I set name="SelectedItem" to selected image:

```
function SelectItem(id) {
var imgId = 'productImage_' + id;
var imgId_element = document.getElementById(imgId.toString());

//my some operations

imgId_element.name = "SelectedItem";
}
```

And take name's value when UnSelect.

```
function UnSelectItem(id) {
var imgId = 'productImage_' + id;
var imgId_element = document.getElementById(imgId.toString());

//my some operations

imgId_element.name = "";
}
```

I want to set unselect image to background of only selected images. When I `Select/Unselect`  any item with `SelectItem()/UnSelectItem()` following `mouseover()/mouseout()` not work.

```
$("img[name='SelectedItem']").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/Content/images/select.png");
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/Content/images/unselect.png");
});
```

HTML is:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/select.png")" id='productImage_@(Model.Id)'  data-id='@Model.Id'  @{if (Model.IsSelected) { <text>name="SelectedItem"</text>} }  alt="" />
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Mixing jQuery with plain DOM manipulation is sort-of confusing. If you're going to use jQuery, you might as well go all-in.

Comment: `imgId` is a string already, you don't need `.toString()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', 'img[name=SelectedItem]', function() {
  this.src = "/Content/images/select.png";
}).on('mouseout', 'img[name=SelectedItem]', function() {
  this.src = "/Content/images/unselect.png";
});
```

By using the 3-argument variant of `.on()`, you set up a **delegated** handler on the `<body>` element. When the mouse events bubble up to that, the handler will check the target element against the selector.

Now, that said, using the "name" property/attribute for `<img>` elements doesn't make a lot of sense; that's not a valid attribute. You'd be better off adding/removing a **class** value:

```
function SelectItem(id) {
  $('#productImage' + id).addClass('SelectedItem');
}
```

and then:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.SelectedItem', function() { ... })
```

etc.  Finally, you'd be better off using the synthetic "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events, as those get over some browser oddities.

Comment: Really great example , it helped me alot